# c#, wpf BitmapImage CopyPixels (8-bit bmp files) sometimes correct, sometimes not

Tags: c#, wpf, bitmapimage

I simply want to convert a previously loaded BMP-File into a byte[][]. It works pretty well for my own testing images (just some black spots on white background) which are all in the 8 bits per pixel format. 
Now I tried the same code for some bitmaps somebody gave me ( also black squares, rectangles on white background) but it's not working as I expected it:

I expected a white pixel to be represented by a value of 255 (and black just by 0 ) in the resulting array, but i found different values there. In one case pixels that are supposed to be white end up with a value of 1 in the array.

Again, all these files are of 8 bit color depth. 
Also, I noticed, when I open the Images in paint, save them again as a 256 color bitmap, then it works. 
So my questions are:

What is causing this problem ?  (Do color palettes maybe play a role ?)
And how can I make it work ?

Here's my amateurish code:

```
public byte[][] ConvertImageToArray (BitmapSource Image)
{
     byte[][] Result = null;
     if (Image != null)
     {
         int Index = 0;
         int size = Image.PixelWidth * Image.PixelHeight * Image.Format.BitsPerPixel/8;
         byte[] RawImg = new byte[size];
         BitmapPalette test = Image.Palette;
         int stride = (Image.PixelWidth * Image.Format.BitsPerPixel) / 8;

         Image.CopyPixels(RawImg, stride, 0);

         Result = new byte[Image.PixelHeight][];
         int Width = Image.PixelWidth;
         for (int i = 0; i < Result.Length; i++)
         {
             Result[i] = new byte[Width];
             for (int k = 0; k < Result[i].Length; k++)
             {
                 Result[i][k] = RawImg[Index++];
             }
         }
     }
     return Result;
}
```

Comment: Could you post the images in question somewhere and provide a link? The problem is likely with them, not your code.

Comment: As a note, there are also pixel formats with a bits-per-pixel value that is not an integer multiple of 8. The stride should then be calculated as `var stride = (bitmap.PixelWidth * bitmap.Format.BitsPerPixel + 7) / 8;`. And of course, if the format is one of `IndexedX`, the values you get aren't color values, but just indices into a color table.

Comment: Oh, thanks for the advice concerning 
And yes, I just learned about indexed colors, that is definitely the issue here.
I just found out that converting the format seems to do the job so far.